# Problems with Wifi on Gnome 16.10 Asus laptop

Tags: drivers, wireless, gnome, asus, 16.10

Just got a new worklaptop, and have been trying for two days to get the wifi working..

As advised in https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2191382

I chose to give up the search and ask you for help, because I have tried all kinds of solutions, to no avail.

Last thing I tried is a symlink from the new driver in /lib/firmware to the older one, because it was trying to load another driver which was not downloaded yet.

( lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      22 okt 21 22:05 iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode -> iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode )

https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/core_release gives the impression that the version my laptop wants is newer than what is being released as stable.

the output of the diags:

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M] (rev a2)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)
```

lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:57ed Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05dc:a817 Lexar Media, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0781:5406 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Micro U3
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
binfmt_misc            20480  1
nls_utf8               16384  1
isofs                  40960  1
rfcomm                 77824  2
cmac                   16384  1
bnep                   20480  2
joydev                 20480  0
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
snd_soc_skl            65536  0
snd_soc_skl_ipc        45056  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_ipc        16384  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_sst_dsp        32768  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_hda_ext_core       28672  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_match      16384  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     45056  1
snd_hda_codec_conexant    24576  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_conexant
i2c_designware_platform    16384  0
i2c_designware_core    20480  1 i2c_designware_platform
snd_soc_core          233472  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
asus_nb_wmi            24576  0
arc4                   16384  2
asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
snd_hda_intel          36864  6
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_core           86016  7 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               110592  8 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_soc_core
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             188416  0
iwlmvm                360448  0
kvm                   598016  1 kvm_intel
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
mac80211              757760  1 iwlmvm
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
intel_cstate           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
iwlwifi               229376  1 iwlmvm
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
cfg80211              581632  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
input_leds             16384  0
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
uvcvideo               90112  0
snd                    86016  25 snd_compress,snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec_conexant, snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,     snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
serio_raw              16384  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
soundcore              16384  1 snd
videobuf2_core         40960  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
idma64                 20480  0
videodev              180224  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
virt_dma               16384  1 idma64
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
mei_me                 40960  0
mei                   102400  1 mei_me
processor_thermal_device    16384  0
intel_lpss_pci         16384  0
shpchp                 36864  0
intel_soc_dts_iosf     16384  1 processor_thermal_device
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
elan_i2c               36864  0
hci_uart               94208  0
btbcm                  16384  2 hci_uart,btusb
btqca                  16384  1 hci_uart
btintel                16384  2 hci_uart,btusb
int3403_thermal        16384  0
bluetooth             552960  33 btrtl,hci_uart,btintel,btqca,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
int3402_thermal        16384  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  3 int3402_thermal,int3403_thermal,processor_thermal_device
asus_wireless          16384  0
intel_lpss_acpi        16384  0
intel_lpss             16384  2 intel_lpss_pci,intel_lpss_acpi
int3406_thermal        16384  0
tpm_crb                16384  0
int3400_thermal        16384  0
acpi_pad               20480  0
mac_hid                16384  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               36864  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
algif_skcipher         20480  0
af_alg                 16384  1 algif_skcipher
dm_crypt               28672  1
uas                    24576  0
usb_storage            73728  3 uas
hid_logitech_hidpp     28672  0
hid_logitech_dj        20480  0
usbhid                 53248  0
nouveau              1572864  1
i915                 1314816  26
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           167936  5
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ttm                   102400  1 nouveau
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 nouveau,i915
cryptd                 24576  4 ablk_helper,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
drm_kms_helper        167936  2 nouveau,i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
r8169                  81920  0
mii                    16384  1 r8169
drm                   368640  14 nouveau,i915,ttm,drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  3
libahci                32768  1 ahci
i2c_hid                20480  0
hid                   118784  5 i2c_hid,usbhid,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
wmi                    16384  3 asus_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
pinctrl_sunrisepoint    28672  0
pinctrl_intel          20480  1 pinctrl_sunrisepoint
video                  40960  4 asus_wmi,int3406_thermal,nouveau,i915
fjes                   28672  0
```

My OS is Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 And the laptop is an Asus Sonicmaster.

Any help is appreciated, and if more information is required, please let me know.

Kind regards,

AntiFTW

EDIT: @chili555, ofcourse:

rfkill list all

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

dmesg | grep iwl

```
[10.274116] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.361476.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[10.275176] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[10.310150] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[10.312328] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[10.312524] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[10.372027] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[10.388272] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[10.393010] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: May we also see: `rfkill list all` and also: `dmesg | grep iwl` Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf <<< "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4"
```

and reboot.